# Capture matched values in regex

Tags: java, regex

I use this regex `\\wx\\w\\w\\w\\w` to split a string. I'm attempting to match `0x0441,a,2,3,4` and `0x0442,f,dws,212` from the following string : `"0x0441,a,2,3,4,0x0442,f,dws,212"`

Using the regex with code below :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadLine {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        final String str = "0x0441,a,2,3,4,0x0442,f,dws,212";

        Arrays.stream(str.split("\\wx\\w\\w\\w\\w")).forEach(split -> System.out.println(split));

    }
}
```

prints :

```
,a,2,3,4,
,f,dws,212
```

I expect the output to be :

```
0x0441,a,2,3,4,
0x0442,f,dws,212
```

How to also capture the matched values `0x0441` & `0x0442` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\wx\\w\\w\\w\\w)"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XFzqx1)

Note that your regular expression can be written more simply with a [quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) (as mentioned by [Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573)).

```
Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\wx\\w{4})"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Good answer! It's better to educate the OP about [quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) e.g. we can write it as `(?=\wx\w{4})` using the quantifier.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Good point. I have updated my answer.